# WebView is just loading white screen

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to start a new activity with a WebView but when I try and load the activity, I am just brought to a white screen.

My Activity just has this as the code

```
public class TrainingVideos extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training_videos);

        WebView trainingWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_trainingVideos);
        trainingWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        trainingWebview.loadUrl(url);
    }    
}
```

with my XML having

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/octtan"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.octitle.ryann.octmobile.TrainingVideos">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_trainingVideos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And my manifest including

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to load the webview settings before loading URL? E.g. enabled JavaScript before loadUrl

Comment: I tried that after posting my question and it had the same result

Comment: I used your code and is working fine with www.google.com

Comment: Make sure your url is not opening pop-ups

Comment: Does the url load in browser?

Comment: I tried the same code with https://www.google.com and it worked fine with that but when I tried to other sites it seems to be hit and miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was an issue with self signed certificates contacting the server I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 trainingWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
trainingWebview.get settings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
trainingWebview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I just tried that after asking this and it has the same result

Comment: Is there any reason for disabling hardwareAccelerated by setting it to false?

Comment: It was another post that I saw that said for some reason it might have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the url in your app and not using your navigator

```
    WebView trainingWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_trainingVideos);

    //New line to open the url in your app
    trainingWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    trainingWebview.loadUrl(url);
    trainingWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```